# Is modular approach in Drupal good for performance?

Tags: performance, drupal, module

Suppose I have to create functionalities A, B and C through custom coding in Drupal using hooks.

Either I can club three of them in custom1.module or I can create three separate modules for them, say custom1.module, custom2.module and custom3.module.

Benefits of creating three modules:

- Clean code
- Easily searchable
- Mutually independent
- Easy to commit in multi-developer projects

Cons:

- Every module entry gets stored in the database and requires a query.

To what extent does it mar the performance of the site?

Is it better to create a single large custom module file for the sake of reducing database queries or break it into different smaller ones?

This issue might be negligible for small scale websites, let the case be for large scale performance oriented sites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal .module files are all loaded with every page load.  There is very little performance related that can be gained or lost simply by separating functions into different .module files.   If you are not using an op code cache, then you can get improved performance by creating .inc files and referencing those files in the menu items in hook_menu, such that those files only get loaded when the menu items are accessed.  Then infrequently called functions do not take up memory space.

File separation in general is a very small performance issue compared to how the module is designed with respect to caching, memory use, and/or database access and structure. Let the code maintenance and dependency issues drive when you do or do not create separate modules.

Answer (score 1):

I would code it based on how often do I need function A , B and C

Actual example:

I made a module which had two needs

1) Send periodic emails based on user preference. Lets call this function A
2) Custom content made in a module . Lets call this function B
3) Social integration . Lets call this function C

So what I did is as Function A is only called once a week I made a separate module for it.

As for Function B and C I put it all together as they would always be called together.

If you have problems with performance then check  out this link . Its a good resource  for performance improvement.

http://www.vmirgorod.name/10/11/5/tuning-drupal-performance

It lists a nice module called boost. I have not used it but I have heard good things about it.

cheers,
Vishal

Comment: Boost is a good module but works only for anonymous users. i personally prefer varnish for anonymous caching.
http://drupal.org/project/varnish

Answer (score 0):

i'm actually interested in:

> Is it better to create a single large custom module file for the sake of reducing database queries or break it into different smaller ones?

I was poking around and found a few things regarding benchmarking the database. Maybe the suggestion here is to fire up the dev version and test. check out [db benchmarking](http://drupal.org/node/79237)

now i understand that doesn't answer specifically but i'd have to say its unique to each environment. I hate to use that type of answer but i truly believe it is. Depends on modules installed, versions used, hardware and os tunables among many other things.